# Javascript addin for Visual Studio 2010 express edition

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express

I am using Visual Studio 2010 express edition and the IDE is good for development. However the javascript features are not that good and hence I was looking for some javascript addin to assist the javascript development. Can anyone suggest one for me.

Note: I tried installing [js-addin](http://code.google.com/p/js-addin/downloads/list) express edition vsix, which did not succeed. I get `MissingReferenceException` in the install log.

Comment: I think Express editions of Visual Studio don't support Add-Ins and extensions.

Comment: @Ash - Actually, Visual Studio 2010 Express allows some extensions. Have a look at the question http://stackoverflow.com/q/7940249/723845

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible.  The express editions of Visual Studio do not support installing Extensions or Add-Ins.  So there is no way to get a JavaScript add-in into an express version.